Iphone camera and gallery permission request issue
i'm creating an flutter ios application where i need camera or photos permission
    Future<bool> _checkAndRequestPermission(Permission permission) async {
    var status = false;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final AndroidDeviceInfo deviceInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
      final int sdkInt = deviceInfo.version.sdkInt ?? 0;
      status =
          sdkInt > 32 ? await permissionPhotos() : await permissionStorage();
    } else {
      print('we are on iphone emulator');
      var status = await permission.status;
      if (status.isDenied || status.isRestricted) {
        status = await permission
            .request(); // Request permission if denied or restricted
      }

      if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
        openAppSettings(); // Direct user to settings if permanently denied
        return false;
      }
      print('return here: ${status.isGranted}');
      return status.isGranted;
    }

    return Future<bool>.value(status);
  }

this is my code where i'm trying to request permission if permission is denied
i also have updated info.plist
and yes this code was working fine few days ago but now it first give permission status as denied then without requesting permission it says permanently denied
i have tried many times but still no results
though it is working fine on android
what is the issue ?
could anyone help..

It is solved now
i updated my Podfile and do following things and boom..
    post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
               '$(inherited)',

               ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
               ##'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',

               ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
               #'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=0',

               ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
               # 'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=0',

               ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
               'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

               ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
               #'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',

               ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
               #'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=0'

               ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
               'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',

               ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
               'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',

               ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
               'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',

               ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
                ##'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1',

               ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
                'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',

               ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
               #'PERMISSION_SENSORS=0'
             ]
    end
  end
end

